# C# and mp3 fade in/out

Tags: c#, sdk, mp3

I am looking for a library to offer me an option to cut mp3 files. I want to cut a certain part of file and fade in/out the volume.

Right now Im using Windows Media Encoder SDK, but it does not have an option to fade in/out or I am not aware of it.

On some forum I noticed that somebody suggested DirectX SDK for fading, but I cant find any documentation regarding this.

If somebody can help, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best option is probably to use the [NAudio](http://www.codeplex.com/naudio) library for .NET, at least for manipulating (fading in/out) the audio data. It does additionally have MP3 reading/writing support, but I'm not sure how complete it is. If it's usuable now, then that library should be able to do everything you perfectly well, and as a bonus all in a fully managed way. At worst, you will require an extra tool to decode/re-encode MP3 files from raw audio/WAV files.

[DirectShow.NET](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/) (a managed wrapper for the Microsoft DirectShow API) might be another option, though this is bound to be painful, given that a) the interface is still effectively COM, b) the DirectShow API is notoriously convoluted and difficult to use.

Comment: Just to wrap things up, I ended up using http://sox.sourceforge.net/